# Trying to print in a sub class from the super class

Tags: java, bluej

At the bottom of the sub class I need the 3 lines from my super class to print using the switch statement.  It won't print `System.out.println(super.display());` because it's obviously `void`.

I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

**The super class:**

```
public void display()
{
        String fullLocation = "";

        switch (location)
        {

                case 'N': case 'n': fullLocation = "North London";
                break;
                case 'S': case 's': fullLocation = "South London";
                break;
                case 'E': case 'e': fullLocation = "East London";
                break;
                case 'W': case 'w': fullLocation = "West London";
                break;
                default: fullLocation = "Central London";
                break;

        }
        System.out.println("The address of this property is at " + address + ".");
        System.out.println("This property is in " + fullLocation);
        System.out.println("This property has " + bedrooms + " bedrooms");
}
```

**The sub class:**

```
public void display()
{

   String buyer = purchaser;

   if(sold == true){

       *System.out.print(super);  ???*

       System.out.println("The price of this property is £" + price + ".");
       System.out.println("The owner of this property is " + purchaser + ".");
   }
    else{
       System.out.println("The startic price for this property is £" + price + ".");
       System.out.println("The property is still on the Market");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just coding `super` doesn't call the superclass version of the method.  For calling a superclass method, you can treat the keyword `super` as if it were an instance of the superclass, calling the method with dot notation:

```
super.display();
```

You can remove the `System.out.println` from that line, because the superclass method has its own printing statements.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write `super.display()` , `System.out.println` is not needed.